# Nginx: map subdomain to a subdirectory on proxied server

Tags: nginx, proxy, rewrite, subdomain

I have domain `example.com` and subdomain `blog.example.com`. I have an Unicorn application running at `localhost:5000`, and use Nginx as a reverse proxy.

I had no issues when running just the `example.com`. However I want to add subdomain support and have some issues.

I have some content at `example.com/blog`. I want `blog.example.com` to point to it, without user knowledge that a rewrite is used. I want to map all URLS, so that:

- `blog.example.com` -> `localhost:5000/blog`
- `blog.example.com/index.php` -> `localhost:5000/blog/index.php`
- `blog.example.com/foo/bar` -> `localhost:5000/blog/foo/bar`

My best attempt so far it this:

```
server
{
  listen 80;
  server_name blog.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/blog/$uri;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

This correctly rewrites `blog.example.com`, but fails with `blog.example.com/index.php`:

```
$ curl -v 'http://blog.example.com'
> GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: blog.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Sun, 26 Mar 2017 12:29:00 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 337
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://blog.example.com/blog/index.php
```

Comment: I think this is something in your blog software configuration that makes it return the redirect.

Comment: No, this is on nginx level. I set up a script at `/blog` that does nothing except printing env info (like `php_info()`) and I'm still getting the 301 from nginx. Also, when it starts to redirect to `/blog`, it creates a loop (`/blog/blog/blog/blog/.../blog/index.php`).

Answer (score 3):

I found that my mistake was at this line:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/blog/$uri;
```

When changed to

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/blog$uri;
```

the proxy works as expected.

[edit]

Even better version, to also pass query string:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/blog$uri$is_args$args;
```

Comment: Do you have a problem with styles and javascripts? The assets in my case throw an error (404)